# Citrix printing problem on centos - hp

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, citrix

I have setup Centos 6.3 - 6.5, installed wine and running Citrix app. I can print perfectly Wine based apps (i.e. wine notepad) but when printing Citrix through wine it is printing ASCII characters.

I have installed hplip-3.14.3 printer is HP Lasetjet Pro 400 M401n.

Do any one have any idea on same? Can some one guide on work around?

Many thanks!

Comment: Citrix is a company, not an application. Which application are you referring to?

Comment: Citrix Presentation Server 4.5